# Pika BlockingConnection throwing wrong exception on Windows

Tags: python, pika

I'm using a [BlockingConnection](http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/adapters/blocking.html) to access RabbitMQ. I'm now trying to handle the case where RabbitMQ becomes unreachable.

According to the [documentation](http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/adapters/blocking.html), when a connection is closed the following happens:

> This is not supported in BlockingConnection. When a connection is
>   closed in BlockingConnection, a pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed
>   exception will raised instead.

On OS X, this is exactly what happens. On Windows, on the other hand, another exception is thrown:

> error: (10038, 'An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket')

Why is that?

I'm using pika 0.9.13 - the latest version.

Comment: Updating to 0.9.14 should fix disconnection related issues.

Comment: I'm on 0.9.14 on Windows and I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I would recommend that you try to move to gmr's (the author of pika) new library rabbitpy, as pika has not seen much love lately. https://github.com/gmr/rabbitpy As an alternative you could also try my pika inspired library https://github.com/eandersson/amqp-storm